# Help center page cites the wrong quote for the "opinion-based" close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

At this page of the help center regarding close reasons:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

The close reason of "Opinion-based" cites the wrong explanation (actually the explanation of the reason "Needs more focus" before):

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

---

It should cite instead:

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

---

Please correct this copy & paste mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately, site moderators cannot edit these pages in the Help Center, presumably because they are shared among all Stack Exchange sites. Therefore, the only way to get this fixed is to have a staff member (such as a CM) edit it. I've added the [[meta-tag:status-review]] to escalate it to someone with the power to make this edit. It is obviously appropriate. Thanks for the suggestion (and for reading the Help Center).

Comment: @CodyGray It's correct on [su] so the sharing part may not be correct.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's interesting. Just to minimize inconveniences, here is the [link](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions) to the same Super User pendant (You linked to general Super User page). - I wonder why the help pages are actually so different in general. IMHO the close reasons who are different between both are better explained on the Super User forum.

Comment: Thanks for help, @CodyGray. Now I come here over 2 weeks later and nothing has changed, no notification or any sign of process at all. I didn't thought it would take so much time to fix such a, in relation easy-fixed, bug.

Comment: 1/2 months later. Still no change or reaction.

Comment: I hope it is correct now. Thank you!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Great.